# how to query and code to display a link table into one view

Tags: mysql, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, join

I cannot get around how to display two tables that are link together in to one view. I am using sql database. I have successfully done only one table which is the getsneakerdetails. It displays all the attributes in the view but when I did the join as you can see it does not let me fetch the other link table.

DAO code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using sneaker_info.data.IDAO;
namespace sneaker_info.data.DAO
{
    public class sneakerDAO : ISneakerDAO
    {
        /*Create the sneakerDAO object*/
        private sneakerEntities _context;
        public sneakerDAO()
        {
            _context = new sneakerEntities();

        }
        /*GetSNeakerRealeses returns a list of sneakers*/
        public IList<sneaker> GetSneakers()
        {
            var categories = from Name in _context.sneakers
                             select Name;
            return categories.ToList();
        }
        public sneakerImage GetSneakersImages(int id)
        {
            IQueryable<sneakerImage> query = from recs in _context.sneakerImages
                                             join x in _context.sneakers on recs.sneake_id equals x.sneake_id
                                             where recs.img_id == id
                                             select recs;
            return query.ToList().First();

        }

        public sneaker GetSneakerDetails(int id)
        {

            IQueryable<sneaker> query = from recs in _context.sneakers
                                        join x in _context.sneakerImages on recs.sneake_id equals x.sneake_id
                                        where recs.sneake_id == id
                                        select recs;

            return query.ToList().First();
        }

        protected void sneakerDetailsWithImages(int id)
        {




        }

    }
}
```

interface code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace sneaker_info.data.IDAO
{
    interface ISneakerDAO
    {
        IList<sneaker> GetSneakers();
        sneakerImage GetSneakersImages(int id);
        sneaker GetSneakerDetails(int id);

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: How can you display LinkedList and Images in code file? be clear and which two links you want to combine? also share some code from view.

Comment: there is no error i am just not able to fetch the other link table to display in one view the getsneakertable should also fetch the sneaker image in one view hope that helped